# Trying to write a Python/pandas function to update rows in a specific column that equal 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm completely stuck and don't know how to start. I want to write a function that replaces the values of zero in the 'age' column with the 'age' values where the 'year' is the same.

Here is a sample dataframe with expected output:

```
Sample df:
'age'   'name'  'year'
0       John    2018
0       John    2019
23      John    2018
24      John    2019


Expected output:
'age'   'name'  'year'
23      John    2018
24      John    2019
23      John    2018
24      John    2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by rows with no `0` values:

```
d = df[df['age'].ne(0)].set_index('year')['age'].to_dict()

df['age'] = df['year'].map(d)
print (df)
   age  name  year
0   23  John  2018
1   24  John  2019
2   23  John  2018
3   24  John  2019
```

If need match by 2 columns use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with replace `0` by `NaN`:

```
df['age'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).groupby(['year','name'])['age'].transform('first')
print (df)
    age  name  year
0  23.0  John  2018
1  24.0  John  2019
2  23.0  John  2018
3  24.0  John  2019
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html):

```
In [1637]: import numpy as np

In [1638]: df.age = df.replace(0, np.nan).groupby('year').age.bfill()

In [1639]: df
Out[1639]: 
    age  name  year
0  23.0  John  2018
1  24.0  John  2019
2  23.0  John  2018
3  24.0  John  2019
```